# Why is ReFS not appropriate for Work Folders

Tags: network-attached-storage, synchronization, btrfs, refs

I'm looking to setup a NAS for a small team. Two main requirements are using it as an archive and a folder syncing. Because I want to make sure that the archive is not prone to bit rot, I've came to the conclusion that I need something that uses either ReFS or btrfs on top of a mirrored volume (I've decided to skip ZFS, because of it's high requirements - a box configured according to FreeNAS guidelines would be to expensive). I'm evaluating Windows now and saw that Work Folders would be perfect for my second requirement. But when I've tried to setup them, Windows forces me to create it on an NTFS volume, but I couldn't find any explanation why. So here are my questions:

Why is ReFS not suited for folder syncing?

Is btrfs also not suited for such things?